# MySQL date format convert "Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500"

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, date-format

I have `"Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500`" date format in MySQL.

I want to convert it to `Y-m-d H:i:s` format within MySQL query. Can anyone please help?

I tried this `DATE_FORMAT("Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500", '%Y-%m-%d H:i:s')` but didn't work.

Comment: what is your datatype in field of date? mysql support only Y-m-d H:i:s and timestamp formate. it may be varchar datatype..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make *two* transformations here, to cover the general case.  First, you need to convert your non standard timestamp into a date, and then you need to format that date in the output you want.  Diagramatically:

```
your timestamp string -> MySQL date -> some other string output
```

Consider this query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%S'),
                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS output
FROM dual;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
     echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500"));
?>
```

Note- In strtotime() funtion you can pass your date value, which you wnats to convert.

Hope this will help!

Comment: The question asked for MySQL, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime() in php..it looks likes.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['col_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` doesn't recognize the string you passed as a date, you have to use `STR_TO_DATE()` and match the string as follows:

```
STR_TO_DATE("Fri, 06 Nov 2015 04:06:05 -0500",'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

This already outputs in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.